# Hex edit over SSH

Tags: ssh, hex

How can you hex edit a file over SSH?  I have tried using hexedit, but it says command not found.  Using xxd gives the hex dump of the file, but how can I actually edit the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`hexedit`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hexedit) should do it.

`hexedit` shows a file both in ASCII and in hexadecimal. The file can be a device as the file is read a piece at a time. You can modify the file and search through it.

Alternatively, you can use `vim` and `xxd` to do the same. Check this answer [How to edit binary files with Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/343/how-to-edit-binary-files-with-vim).

Comment: then do `sudo apt-get install hexedit` (or whatever command your remote system uses to install software).

Comment: I can't do that either, it says 'sudo: command not found', sorry again!

Comment: You could also use `vim`. But if you don't have it either ... I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Oh thanks for the help, I can use Vim and also Nano to edit the file.  I also managed to install hexedit using wget.